# passing session variable from php to as3 doesnot work

Tags: php, actionscript-3

I'm trying to pass session variable from php to as3 in flash, but it is not working.
Actually it is more complex than the code below, but I try to simplify it as possible as I can to identify what the problem is.

php code :

```
<?php

session_start();
$name="";

if(isset($_POST['myrequest']) && $_POST['myrequest'] == "get")
{
    if(isset($_SESSION["currentuser"]))
    {
        $name=preg_replace('#a-z0-9#i',' ',$_SESSION["currentuser"]);
    }

    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
    $link=mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
    mysql_select_db('flash');
    $query2=mysql_query("select * from `account1`where name='$name' " );
    $num2=mysql_num_rows($query2);

    if($num2 > 0)
    {
        echo "var11=$name";
        exit ();
    }
    else
    {
        echo "var_2=no notes recorded for that lesson";
    }

    @mysql_close($link);
}
?>
```

As3 code:

```
var variables:URLVariables=new URLVariables();
var varsend:URLRequest=new URLRequest("http://localhost/ses2.php");
varsend.method=URLRequestMethod.POST;
varsend.data=variables;
var varloader:URLLoader=new URLLoader;
varloader.dataFormat=URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
varloader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,completehandler);
variables.myrequest="get";
varloader.load(varsend);

function completehandler(event:Event):void
{
    trace(event.target.data.var11);
    trace(event.target.data.var_2);
}
```

When I run swf, it traces (var_2) only and it doesn't find a session variable(var11). 
When I run php file without   `if(isset($_POST['myrequest']) && $_POST['myrequest'] == "get")`, it posts session variable properly on localhost without problems, so i think problem in communication between as3 and php, not in php.

Comment: Have you tried accessing your `http://localhost.ses2.php` in the browser to see the response?   Looking at your PHP,  you have an if statement that makes it so you only get one or the other (`var11` **or** `var_2`). If you're getting var_2, then the obvious cause is that your SQL query returned no rows (which isn't a communication problem between flash and PHP)

Comment: yes i tried  that.it is running and posting session variable on localhost, but it cannot pass session variable to as3.why that?

Comment: Probably because when you access it from flash, there is no session created on the php app.  Is your swf running IN the browser (same window) as your other php stuff that creates the session?

Comment: no,i also run it on the same browser of php,but it is not working.

Comment: wait ,please. you meant in your first comment running ses2.php with if statement of request of as3?.i misunderstand you.sorry i try again what you mean and running ses2.php with its full code , and it doesnot post any variable neither var11 nor var_2

Comment: What's the value of `$name`? I assume it's not url encoded...

Comment: sorry I am beginner .how can I make it url encoded?.

Comment: you mean writing    echo "var11=".urlencode ( $name );

Comment: Buddy, try google. This isn't "write my homework" type of website..

Comment: for sure i google it ,but i am not sure if i code it coreectly or not

Comment: echo "var11=".urlencode ( $name ); in php

Comment: the session vraiable passed to as3 still undefined